# How can I combine two props into a third prop when adding to database?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm creating my first project using ASP.NET Core 3.0 using EF Core.  When creating a user (Patient) I want them to be able to enter their first and last names separately in the create view, these will be saved in my database in a FirstName and LastName column respectively.  However, I'm wanting to have both of these fields combined and stored in another column called FullName so I can use it for searching for users.  Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

I've tried with the below code but I'm getting an unhandled exception -

> "SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'FullName',
>   table 'WebPMR.dbo.Patient'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated"

**Model:**

```
public class Patient
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public int TitleId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First Name must be 1-25 characters long")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Last Name must be 1-50 characters long")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        private string _fullName;
        public string FullName 
        {
            get => _fullName;
            set => _fullName = FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
// GET: Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST:Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,FirstName,LastName")] Patient patient)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(patient);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["TitleId"] = new SelectList(_context.Title, "Id", "Description", patient.TitleId);
            return View(patient);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed column

```
Table (
    FirstName VARCHAR(128),
    LastName VARCHAR(128),
    FullName AS FirstName + ' ' + LastName
)
```

Then you can make it **persisted** so you can create an index on it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You can add:
[NotMapped]
attribute to mean you don't have such a field.
Also, instead of a property you could have it as FullName method, or ToString() override.

In searching such data however, you would likely would want to have them separate. It is less common to search by a full name, and in an hospital data probably a receptionist would appreciate to get a list of patients by last name.